# Django: How to get/set model field value if it is put into any data structure?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
class PollResults(models.Model):
    votes_0 = models.IntegerField( default=0 )
    votes_1 = models.IntegerField( default=0 )
    votes_2 = models.IntegerField( default=0 )
    votes_3 = models.IntegerField( default=0 )
    votes = [votes_0,votes_1,votes_2,votes_3]

    def add_vote(self,choice):
        self.votes[choice] = self.votes[choice]+1
```

But, when I call add_vote(0), I am getting: *"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntegerField' and 'int'"*.

Is there any way to make it working? Please don't criticize the database design, this is just an example. The point is how to get/set the field value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are referring to field objects themselves in your `votes` variable. Your code is doing the same thing as `models.IntegerField(default=0) + 1` which is of course invalid.

The simplest solution is to simply get/set new attributes and let the django magic deal with the fields -> value conversions.

```
def add_vote(self,choice):
    attname = 'votes_{0}'.format(choice) # get the attribute name
    value = getattr(self, attname) # get the value
    setattr(self, attname, value+1) # set the value
```

If you want to use this `votes` field of yours to determine index / field, you can access `Field.attname` to figure out the attribute name of your field.

```
def add_vote(self,choice):
    attname = self.votes[choice].attname
    value = getattr(self, attname) # get the value
    setattr(self, attname, value+1) # set the value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I could basically list attribute names (votes=["votes_0","votes_1","votes_2","votes_3"] to make it simplest.

Comment: @pryma, well it would be simplest if you always use votes_XX syntax and look at my first code example.